# MQTT client opens new connections, then closes them

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto

This is shown in the mosquitto log :

```
1636686996: New connection from 192.168.1.10:58779 on port 1884.
1636686996: New connection from 192.168.1.10:52435 on port 1884.
1636686996: New connection from 192.168.1.10:53212 on port 1884.
1636686996: New connection from 192.168.1.10:52612 on port 1884.
1636686996: New connection from 192.168.1.10:60982 on port 1884.
1636686996: New connection from 127.0.0.1:61362 on port 1884.
1636686996: New connection from 192.168.1.10:64731 on port 1884.
1636686996: Client mqtt_0dd8eeee22c90b58 closed its connection.
1636686996: New client connected from 192.168.1.10:55946 as ESP8266Client-1bdf (p2, c1, k15).
1636686996: No will message specified.
1636686996: Sending CONNACK to ESP8266Client-1bdf (0, 0)
1636686996: New client connected from 192.168.1.10:58779 as ESP8266Client-190f (p2, c1, k15).
1636686996: No will message specified.
1636686996: Sending CONNACK to ESP8266Client-190f (0, 0)
1636686996: New client connected from 192.168.1.10:60982 as ESP8266Client-c6b0 (p2, c1, k15).
1636686996: No will message specified.
1636686996: Sending CONNACK to ESP8266Client-c6b0 (0, 0)
1636686996: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:61362 as mqtt_0dd8eeee22c90b58 (p2, c1, k60).
1636686996: No will message specified.
1636686996: Sending CONNACK to mqtt_0dd8eeee22c90b58 (0, 0)
1636686996: New client connected from 192.168.1.10:64731 as ESP8266Client-3a80 (p2, c1, k15).
1636686996: No will message specified.
1636686996: Sending CONNACK to ESP8266Client-3a80 (0, 0)
1636686996: Client ESP8266Client-1bdf closed its connection.
1636686996: Client ESP8266Client-190f closed its connection.
1636686996: Client ESP8266Client-5bbf closed its connection.
```

Client code:

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char * ssid = "........";
const char * password = "........";
const char * mqtt_server = "broker.mqtt-dashboard.com";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char * topic, byte * payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char) payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW); // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW 
    is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH); // Turn the LED off by making the 
    voltage HIGH
  }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT); // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin 
  as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf(msg, 50, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("outTopic", msg);
  }
}
```

I'm using the pubsubclient library. I don't know either it is a network or nodemcu issue.

Comment: The logs show connections coming in, being acknowledged and then closed (by the client); without more info its not possible to tell you why this is happening. Please edit the question and add your client code ([simplify it as much as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: What does the serial output show? Also is that log from multiple devices or just one? Better to just test one at once  and I suggest you move the client ID generation to `setup()` so it stays stable across the uptime of the device to make things easier to track.

Comment: The serial output shows "Attempting MQTT connection..." several times.There are just two clients one is the esp8266 connected to the broker with the random ID changed every since gets connected and the other is a node-red client.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70028256/edit) the question to show the actual serial output rather than paraphrasing, I want to see if the delay `reconnect()` function is actually happening, because to get 6 clients all connecting in the same second from what you say is a single device implies it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot judge this without more information.

I had the same issue multiple times, and the reasons were :

1. The internet connectivity was poor for the client/server so it was reconnecting again and again.

2. When I was dealing with real-time applications, the number of connections was very high, and because of which the dead/weak connections were disconnecting automatically.
3. Don't know why but the connection goes weird if I connect my phone's wifi ( Only 1 specific phone ).